# Is there a way to get the margins previously set by `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`?

Tags: c#, dwm

Is there a way to retrieve the margins that were set by [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512.aspx)?

I've scanned the documentation. I would have expected [`DwmGetWindowAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515.aspx) to be the most logical place to look it up.

(What I would like to do is discern what portion of an inserted child should be painted black to allow Aero glass effects through and what portion should be painted the parent's background colour.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. The developer is expected to know the size of the frame they extended into the client area.

```
MARGINS g_Margins;
g_Margins.cxLeftWidth = 0;
g_Margins.cxRightWidth = 0;
g_Margins.cyTopHeight = 15*fontHeight;
g_margins.cyBottomHeight = 7*fontHeight;

DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(g_hwnd, g_margins);
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Okay. So much for interoperability with other third party libraries.

Comment: @jnm2 My guess is that the host is the one that places the child control, the host decides if the child control is on glass or not. The host should be the one to tell the child now to render. The alternative is that the component library always draw with an alpha channel appropriate for the control's look. When rendered on non-glass, the alpha will be ignored. When rendered on glass, the control will appear as you intend.